# User friendly phpMyAdmin for end users?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have several web applications for different clients, each of which is database driven with a MySQL database. It is very time consuming to write a front-end for each database to allow users to manage the database (insert, delete, create reports, etc).

Is there any type of web-based front end (similar to phpMyAdmin) that is both user friendly and safe (won't allow the user to modify database structure)?

Since I am using shared hosting on GoDaddy, I am unable to set up different users with different permissions for the phpMyAdmin installation...

Thanks!

Comment: If such a thing exists (I don't know of anything better than phpMyAdmin), you probably won't be able to use it to manage a database hosted at Go Daddy.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin can support multiple users and html-based login. You could create a user that simply cannot modify database structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sqlBuddy ( http://sqlbuddy.com/ ) is an ajax based drop-in application that you might want to look at. You can have them log in as the mysql user you set up for their website, and limit that user to just the basics, i.e. CRUD. You can have as many copies of it that you want and they don't interfere with each other, or at least I haven't had any issues with two or three copies at the same time.

Comment: I just installed this, it was very easy. The problem is that my users are not very computer savvy, so I want to make it as easy as possible for them. I wish there was a way that I could save custom reports that they could just go ahead and execute..

Comment: What do you mean exactly by custom reports? If it's just SQL code for them to execute you can always write it as a .sql file then they can upload that file to their database and it will run whatever you want on it. May not be exactly what you were looking for, but that's what I understood you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Go with a smaller, less fully-featured phpadmin tool, and just customise it a little.

At 10kb, [PHP Mini Admin](http://phpminiadmin.sourceforge.net/) would be a good choice.

Or if that's too minimal, check out [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/).